# Copy file and replace string

Tags: rename, cp

I am trying to write a script  that copies the file `log_REPLACE`, and replaces the string `REPLACE` in the name of the file, and within the file with the letter `A` and `B`.

So I want to create `log_A`, and `log_b`, and the string `REPLACE` inside them is replaces with the letter A and B in them respectively.

I'm trying:

```
cp log_REPLACE log_A
cp log_REPLACE log_B
grep -rl REPLACE  | xargs sed -i 's/REPLACE/A/g'
```

but that end up rewriting in both copies (*A and *B). is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop over the possible filename substrings, make the replacements with `sed`, save the STDOUT from `sed` as the desired filename:

```bsh
for i in a b; do
    sed "s/REPLACE/$i/g" log_REPLACE >"log_$i"
done
```

Make necessary changes to meet your need.